# Which android 7.0 sdk components must still be kept to support android 7.1.1

Tags: android, sdk, components

I've run out of disk space attempting to download new system image components for android 7.1.1. I have kept all components for android 7.0 in case some where needed for 7.1.1. For example, there were and still are several system images in android the 7.0 component list that are not in the android 7.1.1 component list and there is no corresponding 'Google APIs, Android 25' to replace 'Google APIs, Android 24'. Which android 7.0 components below can I safely delete to free up space (which now has to be done by digging up the standalone sdk manager from deep in the AppData folder as there is no longer a link to it as there was pre android studio 2.3)?

[image]

Comment: the only thing you need to have for any version is the Android SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `Android SDK Platform` is necessary for development, most of other packages are for emulator.

To delete any package remove it's check-box and click Apply or OK:

[image]

Comment: Uninstalling the 7.0 components got me back 30G and the 7.1.1 system images 10G more, thanks.